# Rails model instance reload avoiding clear saved_changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way in rails to call `.reload` on an instance model without clearing saved_changes?

I wanted to reload an instance model without clearing changed attributes.

Just looked through rails `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty` code. But have not seen anything that can help me.

Here is an example:

Current behavior

```rb
user = User.first
user.update(first_name: "New name")
user.saved_changes
=> {"first_name"=>["John", "New name"]}

user.reload.saved_changes
=> {}
```

Expected behavior

```rb
user = User.first
user.update(first_name: "New name")
user.saved_changes
=> {"first_name"=>["John", "New name"]}

user.reload.saved_changes
=> {"first_name"=>["John", "New name"]}
```

I do not want to change rails behavior, just wanted to know if there is any way to don't let `.reload` remove the dirty changes.

Comment: please illustrate by example the behaviour that you observe, and the behaviour you would like to see.

Comment: I have just edited

Answer (score 0):

No, for what seem like very obvious reasons, [`reload` explicitly clears that data](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/593893c901f87b4ed205751f72df41519b4d2da3/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L57-L62):

```
  def reload(*)
    super.tap do
      @mutations_before_last_save = nil
      @mutations_from_database = nil
    end
  end
```